# Best Option Over MS Project

Tags: pm-software

Can someone provide a good alternative to MS Project 2013.

[How to sequence tasks given time estimates?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9072/how-to-sequence-tasks-given-time-estimates#comment11029_9075)

Comment: [Shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are discouraged by the [FAQ](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq); they are a bad fit for the site. Unless the question contains a fairly rigorous definition of requirements, the answer is likely to be localized in time and rather personal.  I wonder if we couldn't find a way to revise this as a community question. "How to choose PM software?" or "What are the critical requirements for PM software?"

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be a dangerous question.  All tools have various levels of functionality and capability and its set of quirks or weaknesses, all with varying price points.  Seems to me your "best" is one that meets your current set of requirements the best at a price you currently can afford.  I think the answer will change for every new project you jump on to some degree.  I think trying to find an answer for a best will bias you from making a reasonably objective analysis of tool fit in your future.

Personally, I remain tool agnostic.  If it meets my current requirements and I can afford it, it's the best...for right now.

Comment: In summation: "The one that works."